# Why do Thunderbird junk mail controls suddenly yield significant amounts of false positives?

Tags: windows, thunderbird, spam-prevention

I'm using [Thunderbird](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/) basically since forever and still run the initial instance; usually I updated in a timely manner and am using <strike>11.0.1</strike> 17.02 accordingly now.

Approximately four days ago the Thunderbird junk mail controls started to produce an ever since increasing number of false positives (never had that before, thus might have actually noticed it a day late or so due to missing some mails).

It's pretty nasty meanwhile, I need to check the junk folders almost synchronously to my inbox to stay on track.

The false positives don't seem to have much rhyme and rhythm either, i.e. this affects direct 3rd party mails, newsletters, operational emails, and even the BCCs I'm sending to myself, all of which both OpenPGP signed and/or encrypted as well eventually (via [Enigmail](http://enigmail.mozdev.org/)).

Any idea what's going on and how to remedy it eventually? I know that I can reset and retrain the Bayesian filter engine, but given my mail volume I'd rather avoid that.

Comment: with TB17 on Linux I'm running into the same problems since Monday. Do you have any idea what's happening?

Comment: I have still neither a solution nor any clue, sorry (I'm meanwhile using TB 17.02) - the effect has calmed down a bit, i.e. the number of false positives decreased again (might hint towards implicit 'retraining'), but they still happen (which contradicts implicit 'retraining') and I have actually changed my email processing routine to include the junk mail folders as a secondary inbox to be frequently checked as well (and emptied to ease identifying false positives) - obviously this is utterly annoying.